# Select with argument between of two values

Tags: php, codeigniter

how i can select items between two values in codeigniter?

my table:

```
precocib
R$ 21.900,00
25.490,00
R$ 69.990,00
R$ 32.490,00
20.500,00
```

and my code to select this values is like this:

```
$this->db->where("precocib BETWEEN $faixaDe AND $faixaAte");
```

but visitors of my website can put value like this 10.000 or 10 or 10,000.00 and 
when they put values like this i got an error

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00 AND 17490,00' at line 3

SELECT `default_produtos`.* FROM `default_produtos` WHERE `precocib` BETWEEN 17490,00 AND 17490,00
```

so how i can resolve this problem??

Comment: You're not using placeholder and the injected data (which uses localized numbers) is breaking the query syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
$this->db->where("FORMAT(REPLACE(precocib, ',', ''), 2) BETWEEN REPLACE($faixaDe, ',', '') AND   REPLACE($faixaAte, ',', '')");
```

[**REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: This help me but i used another way for solve the problem i put mask in the fields thanks man for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma(,) from the 17490,00 AND 17490,00. I think it will be helpfull for you.